# Error detection in Bluetooth communication with android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, protocols

I have a Sparkfun ["BlueSmirf"](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12580) Bluetooth module (based on the RN-41 module from Rovings) which I use to transmit serial data between a microcontroller and my Java-App.

Now of course I want to be sure that my packets arrive as intended to - so do I have to implement some kind of [error detection and correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_detection_and_correction) on both sides or this is already included in the Bluetooth stack?

According to [this answer from Dennis Mathews](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14507397/6049386) I do not need to worry about data corruption over SPP. The [Sparkfun tutorial](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/using-the-bluesmirf/all) says that "These Bluetooth modems can talk to any other Bluetooth device that supports SPP". I suppose this means that my phone belongs to this list, because I can communicate with the BlueSmirf.

Am I understanding this correctly - meaning - I do not have to care about error control?

Edit: According to the Bluetooth [SPP specification](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=260866&vId=290097):

> For any products that will be transferring large data files and where the receiving device will be subject to radio interference causing packet losses, it is recommended that the Error Control feature in L2CAP (Core Specification V3.0 and later) be utilized by configuring the channel to use Enhanced Retransmission mode.

So obviously this is not the default, and have to be configured somehow, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

> Am I understanding this correctly - meaning - I do not have to care
>   about error control?

Correct ! If you put error controlling then also that should not make anything wrong but generally this is not required any controlling. You an use it without error checking also.

Comment: This sounds good for me, but can you support this with a link or some more info?